# Not able to create Angular 6 Project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create angular 6 project using `ng new Project_Name --style=scss` 
 but it generates an error
[image]
The npm and node versions are

- npm version 5.5.1
- node version v9.2.0

Comment: As mentioned in the error did you try to run the command as root/adminstrator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42985208/5695162

Answer (score 1):

Please try to follow below steps with opening command line in administrative mode.

Right click on command prompt and select "Run As an Administrator".

Solution:

1. Open windows explorer and navigate to:
   C:\Users\"your username"\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
2. Then delete folder named:
   .angular-cli.DELETE
3. Optional, but suggested:
   npm clear cache
4. Then run:
   npm install -g angular-cli

**Note:
.folder names are hidden by default. Show these files on Windows 7**

Answer (score 1):

Follow by the error show up, you need to run the `cmd.exe` by Administrator access (right click and `run as Administrator`)

And then run normally the `angular cli` commands

Answer (score 0):

Delete project folder, run `npm cache clean --force` and then create project again with 
`ng new projectname --style=scss` in administrative mode cmd.

Answer (score -1):

npm install g @angular/cli the command global installation create the problem in accessing the C drive, so installing the angular cli in the project folder will not cause any warning or error:

[image]